# "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" in Python

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

I have installed odoo in my server that has Python 2.7.9. When I try to launch the daemon, I get this error:

```
root@des [/opt/odoo/openerp]# /etc/init.d/odoo start
Starting Odoo Server Daemon (odoo-server):                 [  OK  ]
root@des [/opt/odoo/openerp]# 'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp-server", line 2, in ?
    import openerp
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/__init__.py", line 90
    from . import models
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is Python information:

```
root@des [/opt/odoo/openerp]# python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 20:06:47)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

And this is my environment:

```
root@des [/opt/odoo/openerp]# uname -a
Linux des.desytec.com 2.6.32-042stab104.1 #1 SMP Thu Jan 29 12:58:41 MSK 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

EDIT:

Thanks to Tevfik answer, I have solved the error, however, now a syntax error is produced in Python libraries. How is this possible and hot can I solve it?

```
root@des [/usr/local/lib/python2.7]# /etc/init.d/odoo start
Starting Odoo Server Daemon (odoo-server):                 [  OK  ]
root@des [/usr/local/lib/python2.7]# 'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp-server", line 2, in ?
    import openerp
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/__init__.py", line 47, in ?
    import os
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 49, in ?
    import posixpath as path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 339
    slash, dot = (u'/', u'.') if isinstance(path, _unicode) else ('/', '.')
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

root@des [/usr/local/lib/python2.7]#
```

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Jaime

Comment: What is `.`? is it a path?

Comment: @James_Parsons: It's [relative import syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).

Comment: @jstuardo: Did you screw with your odoo installation in any way? Performing edits to its files or changing configuration?

Comment: No.. I have install odoo files without any modification

Comment: @jstuardo: Well, given that you just screwed with them, I'm not confident you didn't screw with them earlier. It looks like odoo is running on Python 2.4 for some reason, and trying to rewrite bits and pieces of it until the whole thing is valid Python 2.4 is going to produce a horribly mangled system without solving your problem.

Comment: I have downloaded odoo today and followed the steps in this page https://odootricks.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/installing-odoo-8-on-centos-6-with-virtual-python-install, with only 2 differences. I installed last 2.x version of Python and I did not use virtual environment.

Comment: You probably should have used a virtual environment. It sounds like the system's native Python installation and the Python 2.7 you've installed are having bad interactions.

Comment: I have tried installing in virtual environment, however, some packages were not installed correctly, for example, when I run "pip --trusted-host pypi.python.org install pyopenssl" I get a lot of compiler errors, for example,  "c/malloc_closure.h:117: warning: division by zero". How can completely delete Python from my system so that I can start over? maybe by deleting /usr/local/lib/Python2.7 folder is not sufficient.

Comment: I have installed finally python packages but one: lxml... this is the error: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'.... I have spent several hours.... some pages say that I need to install xml first but it is installed. Other pages say that it is a memory problem, which is not my case. What else could be?

Comment: `bugtrack_url` is something that did not exist within the Python 2.4 distutils/setuptools/whatever library, you really ought to ensure you are running Python 2.7. Specifically, `bugtrack_url` is a keyword argument to the `setup` function call in the `setup.py` of a package downloaded from PyPI

Answer (score 0):

try this syntax

```
from «app_name».models import *
```

Comment: Thanks... I have updated question with your solution. Now, the syntax error is present in Python library. I don't know how can this be possible, I know nothing about Python, but I need to install Odoo which was developed in this language.